# What vulnerability are they looking for when they try to access .env file on my webserver?

Tags: security, nginx

In my nginx logs I get a lot of 404s from a number of IP addresses looking for a `/.env` file. I assume they are looking for some kind of vulnerability. I was just wondering what that vulnerability is. Why do so many people hope to find a `/.env` file on my webserver?

Here is an example from my logs file:

`20.51.221.198 - - [20/Nov/2021:17:37:59 +0000] "GET /.env HTTP/1.1" 404 134 "-" "Anarchy99"`

Answer (score 0):

They are searching for secrets like tokens, passwords and similar. When working with docker you can create a [.env file to hold your environment variables in](https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/). If you do something wrong, you may end up sharing this file file with the whole world which is something the crawlers hope for.